# Default value in select Ember js

Tags: ember.js

Hello guys I have model `Currency`. I have fields `name:string`, `default:boolean`. In my db only one record can have default value and i want this record was selected in select tag.

Example:

```
name: Eur default:false

name: USD default: true

name: RUR default: false
```

**I want to have :**

```
<selected>
  <option>Eur</option
  <option selected=selected>USD</option
  <option>RUR</option
</selected>
```

**Route.js**

```
EmberMoney.IncomesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    EmberMoney.Income.find()
  setupController: (controller) ->
    controller.set('currencies', EmberMoney.Currency.find());
```

**incomes.handlebars**

```
// Some output with Incomes records

{{view Ember.Select
       contentBinding="controller.currencies"
       optionLabelPath="content.name"
       optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `Ember.Select` and override `selection` as such:

```
EmberMoney.Select = Ember.Select.extend({
    selection: Ember.computed(function (key) {
      var content = this.get('content');
      if (!content || !content.length) return null;

      return content.findProperty('default', true)
    }).property('content.[]')
});
```

Because `selection` in your subclass doesn't have a `value` parameter, the computed property will get permanently replaced for that instance as soon as the selection is changed.

Note that if you set up a binding for `selection`, `selection` will be overridden almost immediately, and you'll instead have to define this property on the source object or get more complicated:

```
EmberMoney.Select = Ember.Select.extend({
    selection: Ember.computed(function (key, value) {
      if (value === undefined || Ember.isNone(value)) {
          var content = this.get('content');
          if (!content || !content.length) return null;

          return content.findProperty('default', true)
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    }).property('content.[]')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help but i don't understand. In what file it's better to put this extended select? I've put it in view file. Is it ok? That is the right way to render this select? As i rendered in my first post? That doesn't work for me. Sorry for stupid questions.